# how configure appsettings.json to have a different connection string from the project when I'm in local

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, connection-string

I'm on .NET 5 in an API, and in the appsettings.json I have the following:

The project I'm working on has a connection string like this

```
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=someserverAWS.com; initial catalog=ProjectDb; Persist Security Info=True; User Id=lorenz; Password=54321 ; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

but I don't have access to that server so in order to make the code works for me in local I have to change it every time (I'm working on a new feature for example) to something like this

```
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;initial catalog=ProjectDb;Persist Security Info=True;User Id=sa;Password=12345;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

**Both are different, so the question is how can I have something on my local that persists when I pull from the repo but doesn't change the repo file when push?**

Comment: In addition to configuring `appsettings.{ENVIRONMENT_NAME}.json` you can use [`launchsettings.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson) for your local environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple. Two steps

### Step 1. Set your environment variable: `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`

You can add this via the Windows environment variable settings.

Set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Development`

[image]

Or if usually the `launchSettings.json` file will be created under the `/Properties` folder. If you have that file, you can check it that it auto set the environment variable.

[image]

### Step 2. Copy your `appsettings.json` to `appsettings.Development.json`

Now your app will use `appsettings.Development.json` to override the default `appsettings.json` file.

You can add your local debugging values in your `appsettings.Development.json` file.

[image]

And now you can edit your connection string.

I strongly suggest you not let git track the development file.

Comment: This gave some problems with git but at the end it worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create different `appsettings.json` for each environment you have.

`appsettings.Development.json` will be used in debug automatically and
`appsettings.Production.json` will be used automatically in production

`appsettings.json` is the default fallback file for properties that are not overridden in any specific environment file and for environments that does not have a matching file